# Sort products by DESC order in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, product

I wrote this code in `functions.php` file of my active theme:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 
    'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
    function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
     $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'random_list' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'date';
        $args['order'] = 'desc';
        $args['meta_key'] = '';
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['random_list'] = 'DESC SORT';
    return $sortby;
}
```

I am trying to sort products by Desc, but products still sorting by default *(ASC)*.

How can I sort them by DESC?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'default_catalog_ordering_desc', 10, 2 );
function default_catalog_ordering_desc( $q, $query ){
    if( $q->get( 'orderby' ) == 'date' )
        $q->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
}
```

Comment: Kindly, but this is just a minor customization on my answer code… In your question you are just asking to change **default ordering to DESC**. The default `order-by` in woocommerce is `'menu_order title'` but not `'date'`… So this is really not fair. If you do it this way, nobody will answer your questions… please think about it. I hope you will react in the right way, removing this…

Answer (score 8):

You can use a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_product_query`** action hook this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'default_catalog_ordering_desc', 10, 2 );
function default_catalog_ordering_desc( $q, $query ){
    if( $q->get( 'orderby' ) == 'menu_order title' )
        $q->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme) or in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

Answer (score 3):

You need to decide first that by which field you want to sort either price title etc. But i have written all the possible ways u can use it,

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args','custom_query_sort_args' );

function custom_query_sort_args() {

```
    // Sort by and order
    $current_order = ( isset( $_SESSION['orderby'] ) ) ? $_SESSION['orderby'] : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

    switch ( $current_order ) {
        case 'date' :
            $orderby = 'date';
            $order = 'desc';
            $meta_key = '';
        break;
        case 'price' :
            $orderby = 'meta_value_num';
            $order = 'asc';
            $meta_key = '_price';
        break;
        case 'title' :
            $orderby = 'meta_value';
            $order = 'asc';
            $meta_key = '_woocommerce_product_short_title';
        break;
        default :
            $orderby = 'menu_order title';
            $order = 'asc';
            $meta_key = '';         
        break;
    }

    $args = array();

    $args['orderby']        = $orderby;
    $args['order']          = $order;

    if ($meta_key) :
        $args['meta_key'] = $meta_key;
    endif;

    return $args;
```

}

Comment: what is deferent with my code? i want sort by date desc and i already try  $args['orderby'] = 'date';
        $args['order'] = 'desc';

Comment: Can u explain me what does this mean if ( 'random_list' == $orderby_value )

Comment: First u have to decide about the field in switch case then u can proceed it further as i have shown already.

Comment: i try your code too! sort by date works like before but is asc and order desc not working

Answer (score 1):

This code should be added to `functions.php` of your theme

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'custom_default_catalog_orderby');

function custom_default_catalog_orderby() {
     return 'date'; // Can also use title and price
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```
/**
 * This code should be added to functions.php of your theme
 **/

add_filter('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'custom_default_catalog_orderby');

function custom_default_catalog_orderby() {
     return 'date'; // Can also use title and price
}
```

I found it here https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/1622323

Answer (score 0):

Another snippet in the comments of Mike Jolley's Gist worked for me:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_default_catalog_orderby');

function custom_default_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
if(!isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ) {
$args['orderby'] = 'date';
$args['order'] = 'dsc';
return $args;
}
}
```

This forces the most recent products to appear first, which in my client's case was only working on the main Shop page but not on Product Category archives. This snippet fixed it, others did not. The bigger question for me is why WooCommerce still has so many major bugs!

Ref: https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/1622323