# Set default admin order for shop order

Tags: woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to sort, by default, shop order in descending order:

```
edit.php?post_type=shop_order&orderby=date&order=desc
```

There is a solution for ordering product using `default_catalog_ordering_desc` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47629492/858782) but I can't find the equivalent for the shop order.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

woocommerce using Wordpress WP_List_Table and in order to modify the order by you can use the following function:

```
function set_orderby_in_admin($wp_query)
{

    global $pagenow; 
    if (is_admin() && 'edit.php' == $pagenow && !isset($_GET['orderby']) && isset($_GET['post_type']) == 'shop_order') {

        $wp_query->set('order', 'DESC'); //You can change it to ASC
    }
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'set_orderby_in_admin', 5);
```

Test it and working :)

Comment: Thank you @kashalo for this code! sadly it is not working, I'm trying to check what can be wrong with my theme.

Comment: no problem did you tried to increase the priority ?

Comment: The code is ok, sorry, problem came from the plugin “Intuitive Custom Post Order“ overriding the sort-ability. Thanks!